# simplify (a + b*(c+d)) / (c+d) in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Given an expression like

```
a + b⋅(c + d)
─────────────
    c + d
```

I would like to use sympy to simplify it to:

```
  a      
───── + b
c + d
```

It works when I substitute (c+d) to e and back:

```
import sympy as sp
a,b,c,d,e = sp.symbols('a b c d e')
expr = (a + b*(c+d)) / (c+d)
expr = expr.subs({(c+d):e}).simplify().subs({e:c+d})
print( sp.pretty(expr) )
# prints
#   a      
# ───── + b
# c + d
```

Why is this? Is there a way to do it without substitution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `apart` helps simplifying fractions :

```py
expr = sp.apart((a + b*(c + d))/(c + d), a)
```

Output is:

```
   a      
 ───── + b
 c + d
```

Comment: As there are several variables, apart should be given another argument. No matter which one you give, the result will be the simplified fraction.